# Rails - how to correctly implement a payment/booking process

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm building an events app in rails and I'm using Stripe to collect my payments. It took me a while but I've got payments working. However, when I try and increase the quantity of spaces to book, the system will only take one payment. So if an event is £10 per 'space' and someone wants to book 5 spaces, regardless of the fact the payments form states the correct amount (£50 in this example), only £10 is collected. 
I'm pretty sure this is an MVC issue but can't seem to spot how to resolve it. In my views I have the following code -

**bookings.new.html.erb**

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Confirm Your Booking</h2>
        </div>
                  <div class="calculate-total">
                              <p>
                                  Confirm number of spaces you wish to book here:
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="1"  min="1" value="1" class="num-spaces">
                              </p>
                                <p>
                                    Total Amount
                                    £<span class="total" data-unit-cost="<%= @event.price %>">0</span>
                                </p>
                          </div>





                <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>



                 <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                      <span>Card Number</span>
                      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <label>
                  <span>CVC</span>
                  <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
                    </label>
                    <span> / </span>
                    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">    

               <%= form.button :submit %>


            </div> 

<% end %>
<% end %>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.calculate-total input').on('keyup change', calculateBookingPrice);

function calculateBookingPrice() {
  var unitCost = parseFloat($('.calculate-total .total').data('unit-cost')),
      numSpaces = parseInt($('.calculate-total .num-spaces').val()),
      total = (numSpaces * unitCost).toFixed(2);

  if (isNaN(total)) {
    total = 0;
  }

  $('.calculate-total span.total').text(total);
}

  $(document).ready(calculateBookingPrice)

</script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

(code for stripe)
```

This works fine on the actual payments page as the example below shows -

[image: Payment form with quantity function]

So, for this example I've used an @event.price of £1 per space/booking. However, if I go ahead and process this booking, rather than £3 that is collected by Stripe, it only shows as £1.

I think this may have to do with the fact @event.price is what I'm expressing in my views, however,when I replace @event.price with @booking.total_amount I then only get the total amount in my payment form (as above) showing as zero and regardless of what I do with the quantity function it stays at zero.

As you can see from the views code my quantity function is handled with some javascript. Am I missing something from this function to make this work?

Do I have the correct params in my controller? Here's my controller code -

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
     class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        # booking form
        # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
        # which person is booking the event?
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@total_amount = @event.price * @booking.quantity


    end

    def create

        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user

            if 
                @booking.reserve
                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_path(@event)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end
    end


    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity, :event_id, :stripe_charge_id, :total_amount)
    end



end
```

Here's my model code with validations -

**Booking.rb**

```
     class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user


    validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
    validates :quantity, :total_amount, presence: true

    def reserve
        # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
        self.valid?



                # Free events don't need to do anything special
                if event.is_free?
                save!

                # Paid events should charge the customer's card
                else

                    begin
                        self.total_amount = event.price * self.quantity
                        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                            amount: total_amount * 100,
                            currency: "gbp",
                            source: stripe_token, 
                            description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
                        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
                        save!
                    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
                    errors.add(:base, e.message)
                    false
                end
            end 

    end
end
```

This has had me stumped for a while. I'm pretty new to Rails so feel sure a more experienced eye can spot where I'm going wrong. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nobody’s gonna walk through 2K of text and images.

Comment: Also, please take the time to format your code properly.... It makes things so much easier to read. (Note: It is a strong convention in ruby to use **2 spaces** for indentation.)

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. I've edited the question. I'd be really grateful if you could offer any solutions you may have.

Comment: I'm probably not going to be real popular for this, but it needs to be said.  Your question and code betray a lack of understanding of very basic principles of creating a system like this.  I don't know if you're getting paid, but you really need expert help (and I don't mean answers on SO).  If you're going to do it, you should first work through the standard Rails book and perhaps another smaller project.  You're dealing with credit cards, logins, and other people's money - these are things that should be done only with a deeper understanding of how to build this properly.

Comment: That's fair enough, I have no issue with your honesty. No, I'm not getting paid, I'm building this for myself. How does one gain a deeper understanding of something without attempting to build it in the first instance? How does one 'scale down' a payment system - it either takes your payment or it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not a line by line fix but rather a nudge in the correct direction.

You are cramming everything into a far too limited set of models and controllers.

I get it - having "too many classes" might seem scary at first. But having parts that do one job and do it well is better than having a few god classes that encapsulate the entire domain. The later is a maintenance nightmare.

Let for example consider the case where a user wants to book 2 adult and one child. Your single booking model is just not cut it.

```
# respresents an order
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:open, :payed]
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :items
  has_many :payments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items

  # get a sub_total (minus taxes)
  def sub_total
    items.map(&:sub_total).sum
  end

  def grand_total
    sub_total + taxes
  end
end

# represents an item (a seat for example) in a booking
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booking

  def sub_total
    (price - rebate) * quantity
  end
end

# respresents a payment attached to a booking
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booking

  # charges payment to stripe and saves
  def charge!
  end
end
```

You are also going to want to have separate controllers for each job:

```
class BookingsController < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_action :set_event, only: [:new, :create]

  # GET /bookings/:booking_id
  # Show a users
  def show
    @booking = Booking.joins(:event, :payments).find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /events/:event_id/bookings/new
  def new
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(user: current_user)
  end

  # POST /events/:event_id/bookings
  def create
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params) do |b|
      b.user = current_user
    end

    if @booking.save
      if @booking.free?
        redirect_to @booking
      else
        redirect_to new_payment_path(@booking)
      end
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private 

     def set_event
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
     end

     def booking_params
       params.require(:booking).permit(items_attributes: [:foo, :bar])
     end
end
```

---

```
class PaymentsController < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_action :set_booking

  # GET /bookings/:booking_id/payments/new
  def new
    @payment = @booking.payments.new 
  end

  # POST /bookings/:booking_id/payments
  def create
    @payment = @booking.payments.new do |p|
      p.total = @booking.grand_total
    end

    if !@payment.valid?
      render :new
    else
      if @payment.charge!
        redirect_to @booking, success: 'Thank you for your payment!'
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_booking
      @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    end

    def payment_params
      params.require(:payment).permit(:foo, :bar)
    end
end
```

### But I want to have the whole thing in a single page!

Doing the whole thing as a single form / post request creates a very brittle and complicated flow with a crazy amount of code paths in the controller.

Additionally your javascript code leaves it wide open for a malicious user to set whatever price they deem fit by altering the DOM.

Learn how to do it properly the synchronous way first. Once that works you can add JSON responses to the controllers and implement the flow as a number of AJAX calls.

Comment: You'll also want a model attached to Event which holds the different types of fares.

Comment: The first payment system I worked on was just two monster PHP scripts and a bunch of SOAP calls and it had pretty much every problem that your solution does - by splitting it into a series of steps I was able to make it much more robust and it actually improved the conversion rate.

Comment: Thanks for all the detail above. Think you're right - I need to re-think how I'm doing this. appreciate the detail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you simply change the `<span>` tag showing the total amount, rather than the data sent to the server/stripe itself. This line:

```
$('.calculate-total span.total').text(total);
```

Simply updates the **textual** value, rather than the actual parameter sent to your server.

I think you can validate this by inspecting the parameters sent to your `BookingsController`. If you print out your `params` in the controller I suspect you'll see that the `quantity` parameter is not being updated by your Javascript.

I can't really remember how `simple_form` works, but you should be able to add a hidden input field for your `quantity` attribute, and then set this via your Javascript function. Something like this:

```
function calculateBookingPrice() {
  var unitCost = parseFloat($('.calculate-total .total').data('unit-cost')),
      numSpaces = parseInt($('.calculate-total .num-spaces').val()),
      total = (numSpaces * unitCost).toFixed(2);

  if (isNaN(total)) {
    total = 0;
  }

  $('.calculate-total span.total').text(total);

  // assumes there's an input field with id "booking-quantity".
  $('#booking-quantity').val(total); 
}

$(document).ready(calculateBookingPrice)
```

Comment: Is it something I need to change in my stripe code also, then? I haven't shown the stripe code in my question as I wasn't sure if it was necessary and have been told to edit the amount of code being shown.